# Custom Manager to filter objects on site but not in admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-managers

I followed [this example](http://terrarum.net/development/soft-deleting-with-django.html) and it works great but I'm wondering if I can put in an exception so that when I am in the admin all objects show up (active and inactive). This might be simple but I can't find how to do it in the docs.

Here's what my manager looks like now:

```
class ShareManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(ShareManager, self).get_query_set().filter(active=True)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several solutions that come to mind:

1. define what queryset to use for change list with [ModelAdmin.queryset()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.queryset).
2. install 2 managers on your model, the first one that admin finds will be used as the default one AFAIK.

   ```
   class SomeThing(models.Model):
      objects = models.Manager()
      shares = ShareManager()
   ```
3. add new method on your custom manager that returns only active stuff and leave `get_query_set` as it is by default.

   ```
   class ShareManager(models.Manager):
       def get_active_items(self):
           return self.get_query_set().filter(active=True)
   ```

**Follow-up**

I think the most suitable solution in your case would be combining #1 and variation of #2.

Set your custom manager as `objects` so everyone can access it (I think this should work for your reusability problem) and also install default manager on your model and use it in `ModelAdmin.queryset()`.

```
    class SomeThing(models.Model):
       objects = ShareManager()
       admin_objects = models.Manager()
```

I should have included `ModelAdmin.queryset()` method example too, so here it is.

```
    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = self.model.admin_objects.get_query_set()
        # TODO: this should be handled by some parameter to the ChangeList.
        # otherwise we might try to *None, which is bad ;)
        ordering = self.ordering or () 
        if ordering:
            qs = qs.order_by(*ordering)
        return qs
```

Note the line `qs = self.model.admin_objects.get_query_set()` is working with `admin_objects` 
 which is the instance of plain manager and includes unpublished items.

The rest of this implementation of `queryset` method is default Django's implementation which usually calls `qs = self.model._default_manager.get_query_set()`.

I hope this clears things up a bit.

Comment: Thanks for multiple solutions, it is helping me to understand more. A couple questions:

For #1, how do I get all of the objects as the queryset if I leave the custom Manager in place? 

#2 and #3 also work, but I run into problems when I use reusable apps like queryset=TaggedItem.objects.get_by_model(Share, tag).

Comment: I've forgot to put an example of `queryset` method.

Comment: They renamed the `queryset` method to `get_queryset` in Django 1.6. The old name is now [deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset).

Comment: I am using django==1.7.7 and I had to change ```_default_manager``` to ```_base_manager``` to get it to work like this ```qs = self.model._base_manager.get_queryset()```